# Getting a int32_t or a int64_t value from a char array

Tags: c++, arrays

An operation I need to perform requires me to get one int32_t value and 2 int64_t values from a char array

the first 4 bytes of the char array contain the int32 value, the next 8 bytes contain the first int64_t value, the the next 8 bytes contain the second. I can't figure out how to get to these values. I have tried;

```
int32_t firstValue = (int32_t)charArray[0];
int64_t firstValue = (int64_t)charArray[1];
int64_t firstValue = (int64_t)charArray[3];

int32_t *firstArray = reinterpet_cast<int32_t*>(charArray);
int32_t num = firstArray[0]; 
int64_t *secondArray = reinterpet_cast<int64_t*>(charArray);
int64_t secondNum = secondArray[0];
```

I'm just grabbing at straws. Any help appreciated

Comment: `int32_t *firstArray = reinterpet_cast<int32_t*>(charArray);` should actually work. Is it not?

Comment: Yes I can actually get the array, but how do I get the 2nd and third value? they're 64 bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
int32_t value1 = *(int32_t*)(charArray +  0);
int64_t value2 = *(int64_t*)(charArray +  4);
int64_t value3 = *(int64_t*)(charArray + 12);
```

Note that this could potentially cause misaligned memory accesses. So it may not always work.

---

A more robust solution that doesn't violate strict-aliasing and won't have alignment issues:

```
int32_t value1;
int64_t value2;
int64_t value3;

memcpy(&value1,charArray +  0,sizeof(int32_t));
memcpy(&value2,charArray +  4,sizeof(int64_t));
memcpy(&value3,charArray + 12,sizeof(int64_t));
```

Comment: [Edsger Dijkstra does not approve of your first solution.](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/edsger-dijkstra-quick-and-dirty.jpg)

Comment: Thank You very much, the top approach should fit my needs just fine and Ive seen it before now that I'm seeing it again.

Comment: @Miek Just be aware that the first solution is not guaranteed by the standard - even though it'll probably work on all modern compilers with `sizeof(int32_t) == 4` and `sizeof(int64_t) == 8`

Comment: @Mystical Thank You, I have used the other method before as well now that I see it. I will use it instead as this need to be bullet proof code.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
typedef struct {
   int32_t firstValue;
   int64_t secondValue;
   int64_t thirdValue;
} hd;

hd* p = reinterpret_cast<hd*>(charArray);
```

now you can access the values e.g. p->firstValue

EDIT: make sure the struct is packed on byte boundaries e.g. with Visual Studio you write `#pragma pack(1)` before the struct

Comment: then a matter of setting bounday pack to byte e.g. #pragma pack(1)

Comment: Padding can prevent this from working... you could use `#pragma pack` directives but that isn't too portable.

Comment: when you start casting from char array to ints you are probably not so concerned of being portable anyway.

Comment: I believe this is not only not portable, but UB (unless the VS documentation explicitly says otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any alignment concerns, the ideal solution is to copy the bytes out of the buffer into the target objects.  To do this, you can use some helpful utilities:

```
typedef unsigned char const* byte_iterator;

template <typename T>
byte_iterator begin_bytes(T& x)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<byte_iterator>(&x);
}

template <typename T>
byte_iterator end_bytes(T& x)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<byte_iterator>(&x + 1);
}

template <typename T>
T safe_reinterpret_as(byte_iterator const it)
{
    T o;
    std::copy(it, it + sizeof(T), ::begin_bytes(o));
    return o;
}
```

Then your problem is rather simple:

```
int32_t firstValue  = safe_reinterpret_as<int32_t>(charArray);
int64_t secondValue = safe_reinterpret_as<int64_t>(charArray + 4);
int64_t thirdValue  = safe_reinterpret_as<int64_t>(charArray + 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

if `charArray` is a 1 byte `char` type, then you need to use `4` and `12` for your 2nd and 3rd values